# Oracle 21c PRAGMA autonomous_transaction causes infinite execution

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle21c

Exectuion of provided code causes infinite execution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UnosRokPlacanja
BEFORE INSERT ON StavkaFaktureKD
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    rok_placanja_temp DATE;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    BEGIN
        SELECT rok_placanja
        INTO rok_placanja_temp
        FROM FakturaKupac
        WHERE broj_fakture_kupac = :new.broj_fakture_kupac;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ZABRANAPROMENEROKAPLACANJA DISABLE';
        :new.rok_placanja := rok_placanja_temp;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ZABRANAPROMENEROKAPLACANJA ENABLE';
        COMMIT;
    END;
```

Purpose of the trigger is to modify property rok_placanja during insertion in StavkaFaktureKD table. This property cannot be modifyed directly using UPDATE statement, because there is another trigger which prevents this (because of business logic). When new record is inserted in StavkaFaktureKD, before inserting, trigger UnosRokPlacanja is activated and it retrieves rok_placanja from referenced record in FakturaKupac table. Retrieved rok_placanja will replace rok_placanja of the new record.

I'm going to provide some more scripts to make problem reproducible.

```
CREATE TABLE FakturaKupac (
        broj_fakture_kupac INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        kupac_PIB INT not null, 
        broj_ponude INT not null, 
        broj_racuna NUMBER, 
        rok_placanja DATE, 
        datum_dokumenta DATE, 
        ukupna_cena NUMBER,
        CONSTRAINT faktura_kupac_kupac
            FOREIGN KEY(kupac_PIB, broj_ponude)
            REFERENCES PonudaKupac(kupac_PIB, broj_ponude)
    );

CREATE TABLE StavkaFaktureKD (
    broj_stavke INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    broj_fakture_kupac INT not null, 
    kolicina NUMBER, 
    jedinicna_cena NUMBER,
    rok_placanja DATE,
    CONSTRAINT broj_fakture_kd_stavka_fakture
        FOREIGN KEY(broj_fakture_kupac)
        REFERENCES FakturaKupac(broj_fakture_kupac)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZabranaPromeneRokaPlacanja
BEFORE UPDATE OF rok_placanja ON StavkaFaktureKD
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Nije moguca izmena vrednosti roka placanja!');
END;
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? seems like a hack of some sorts.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Why are you disabling and enabling a trigger while you execute a *select* statement? That seems very odd. What does that trigger do; and is it also on the table this trigger is against, StavkaFaktureKD? I would imagine that might cause a problem with blocking - the alter waiting for the insert to complete perhaps. (But then you might expect Oracle to throw a deadlock error?)

Comment: Why does this need to be an autonomous transaction ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=28dbb12eebe5b728b940213cddec69a2))? Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `CREATE TRIGGER` statements for **ALL** the relevant triggers; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a description of the problem you are trying to solve (not just the XY-problem with the trigger); the `INSERT` statement used to trigger the trigger; the errors; and the expected behaviour.

Comment: @MT0 this has to be autonomous transaction because EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement executes COMMIT, but commit is not allowed to be executed inside the trigger. So l had to make it autonomous transaction to make it possible to execute EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. I think l found what causes the problem, l'm going to try to explain that in the next comment.

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right, l did not structure it well. Disabling and enabling should surround only :new.rok_placanja := rok_placanja_temp; statement.

Comment: It doesn't make sense around the assignment either. As MTO said, edit your question to explain what you are actually trying to achieve, with all the relevant DDL. (And being picky: `execute immediate` doesn't commit; the `alter` statement you are executing does, like all DDL.)

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, you are right, `alter` does it. I posted some additional DDL